# C++ "Unable to read memory" when accessing pointer object from inherited class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0108C6E9 in myprojectname.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000028.
```

However, this only happens when I call a function from the base class via the derived class.

derived class:

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"

class Space;
class Enemy : public Player{
public:
    void init(Space * s);

private:
    //Space * space = nullptr;
};
```

CPP file:

```
#include "Space.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Player.h"

void Enemy::init(Space * s) {
    //space = s;
}
```

I need a pointer to the space object because my base class also needs that. I am not sure if this is needed.

This is how I call the functions of the base(Player) class:

```
space->getEnemy().drawPlayer(); //FIRST I GET THE OBJECT OF THE DERIVED(ENEMY CLASS) AND THAN I CALL A FUNCTION FROM THE BASE CLASS(PLAYER CLASSS)
```

The error message "Unable to read memory" happens in getter functions in a class that the base class needs(for example a pointer to the window).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I forgot to tell: I initialize that space pointer to my import class named Space, in every class of my project. The program works fine with those space pointers if I don't call the inherited stuff of Enemy class

Space.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Window.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Text.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Enemy.h"

#include <ctime>

class Space {
public:
    void init();
    int getStartTime();

    Window & getWindow();
    Game & getGame();
    Input & getInput();
    Text & getText();
    Player & getPlayer();
    Enemy & getEnemy();

private:
    Text textObj;
    Window windowObj;
    Game gameObj;
    Input inputObj;
    Player playerObj;
    Enemy enemyObj;

    int startTime = clock();
};
```

Space.cpp:

```
#include "Space.h"

//PASSING THE SPACE CLASS OBJECT TO THE INIT FUNCTIONS OF THE OTHER CLASSES
void Space::init(){
    windowObj.init(this);
    gameObj.init(this);
    inputObj.init(this);
    textObj.init(this);
    playerObj.init(this);
    enemyObj.init(this);

    //STARTING THE GAME ACTUALLY
    windowObj.createWindow();
}

Enemy & Space::getEnemy() {
    return enemyObj;
}

Window & Space::getWindow(){
    return windowObj;
}

Game & Space::getGame() {
    return gameObj;
}

Input & Space::getInput() {
    return inputObj;
}

Text & Space::getText() {
    return textObj;
}

Player & Space::getPlayer(){
    return playerObj;
}

int Space::getStartTime(){
    return startTime;
}
```

Player.h(has space pointer):

```
#pragma once

class Space;
class Player {
public:
    void init(Space * s);
    void drawPlayer();
    void setPlayerXSpeed(float speed);
    void move();
    void jump();
    void checkFalling();
    void setJumping(bool value);
    void setAttacking(bool value);
    void projectileAttack();

    float getPlayerX();
    float getPlayerY();

private:
    Space * space;

    int sprites = 8;
    int chanceToMove = 0;
    int times = 0;
    int spriteCount = 0;

    float spritePart = 0.0f;
    float spritePiece;
    float playerX = -0.7f;
    float playerY = -0.42f;
    float playerXSpeed = 0.0f;
    float playerYSpeed = 0.0f;

    bool ableToChangeY = true;
    bool jumping = false;
    bool falling = false;
    bool strafeRight = true;
    bool attacking = false;
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Space.h"

#include <SDL2\SDL_opengl.h>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_JUMP_HEIGHT 0.2f
#define SPAWN_X -0.42f

void Player::init(Space * s){ //INITIALIZING SPACE CLASS OBJECT
    space = s;
    spritePiece = 0.125f;
}

void Player::drawPlayer(){
    glPushMatrix();
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, space->getWindow().getTexture(1));
            glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                    //PART OF THE SPRITESHEET                     DRAWING COORDINATES
                    glTexCoord2f(spritePart, 0.0f);               if (strafeRight) { glVertex2f(playerX        , playerY + 0.52f); } else { glVertex2f(playerX        , playerY + 0.52f); }
                    glTexCoord2f(spritePart + spritePiece, 0.0f); if (strafeRight) { glVertex2f(playerX + 0.13f, playerY + 0.52f); } else { glVertex2f(playerX - 0.13f, playerY + 0.52f); }
                    glTexCoord2f(spritePart + spritePiece, 1.0f); if (strafeRight) { glVertex2f(playerX + 0.13f, playerY)        ; } else { glVertex2f(playerX - 0.13f, playerY        ); }
                    glTexCoord2f(spritePart, 1.0f);               if (strafeRight) { glVertex2f(playerX        , playerY)        ; } else { glVertex2f(playerX        , playerY        ); }
                glEnd();
            glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void Player::move(){
    chanceToMove++;
    if (!attacking){ //NORMAL WALK ANIMATION
        if (playerXSpeed != 0.0f) {
            if (spriteCount != sprites - 3) { //IF CURRENT PART IS NOT THE LAST PART
                if (chanceToMove % 4 == 0) { //SO THE ANIMATION IS NOT AS FAST AS SANIC IS
                    spritePart += spritePiece;
                    spriteCount++;
                }
            }else {
                spritePart = 0.0f;
                spriteCount = 0;
            }
        }else {
            spritePart = 0.0f; //ALSO RESET
        }
    }else { //ATTACKING
        spritePart = spritePiece * (sprites - 2); //ATTACK SPRITE
        projectileAttack();
        if (times == 5) {
            attacking = false;
            times = 0;
        }else {
            times++;
        }
    }

    if (playerXSpeed < 0) { //IF PLAYER IS MOVING LEFT
        strafeRight = false;
    }else {
        strafeRight = true; //MOVING RIGHT
    }

    if (jumping) {
        jump();
    }

    playerX += playerXSpeed; //UPDATING PLAYER POSITIONS
    playerY += playerYSpeed;
}

void Player::checkFalling() {
    if ((playerX < space->getGame().getPlatformLeft() - 0.1f || playerX > space->getGame().getPlatformRight() - 0.05f) && playerY < -0.4f) { //IF PLAYER JUMPED OFF THE PLATFORM
        ableToChangeY = false;
        playerYSpeed = -0.03f;
    }if (playerY < -2.0f) { //IF PLAYER FELL TO DEATH(RIP)
        space->getGame().stopGame();
    }
}

void Player::setJumping(bool value){
    jumping = value;
}

void Player::setAttacking(bool value){
    attacking = value;
}

void Player::projectileAttack(){

}

void Player::jump(){
    spritePart = spritePiece * (sprites-1); //JUMPING SPRITE
    if (ableToChangeY) { //IF PLAYER IS NOT FALLING RIP
        if (playerY < MAX_JUMP_HEIGHT && !falling) { //WHILE THE PLAYER DID NOT PASS THE MAXIMUM JUMP HEIGHT
            playerYSpeed = 0.03f;
        }else { //IF THE PLAYER JUMPED TOO HIGH
            falling = true;
            if (playerY > SPAWN_X) {
                playerYSpeed = -0.03f;
            }else { //PLAYER IS BACK ON EARTH
                jumping = false;
                falling = false;
                playerYSpeed = 0.0f;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Player::setPlayerXSpeed(float speed){
    playerXSpeed = speed;
}

float Player::getPlayerX()
{
    return playerX;
}

float Player::getPlayerY(){
    return playerY;
}
```

**EDIT MAIN FUNCTION**

```
#include "Space.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2\SDL.h>
#include <SDL2\SDL_opengl.h>
#include <SDL2\SDL_ttf.h>
#undef main

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    TTF_Init();

    Space space;
    space.init();

    std::cout << "Type something and press ENTER to quit..." << std::endl;
    char temp;
    std::cin >> temp;

    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might have more luck if you post a more complete compiling example of the problem.

Comment: Does the `drawPlayer()` method on base rely on the pointer `space` being valid? If so, you need to initialize it first. You could declare `space` as protected in the base class, then assign the passed in `s` pointer to it in the derived `init` method.

Comment: Also 0x00000028 is a very low number for a valid memory address for you to be accessing, I would expect that you are getting this error because Space* space has not been initialized (correctly), but without more info it's difficult to tell.

Comment: In your Enemy.cpp file you do not need to include Player.h. You are already including Enemy.h which already includes Player.h. This can cause circular include definitions. As for the Space object that the Enemy class has you are passing a pointer into the Enemy::init() function which is a stack copy of the object. I do not see where you are storing this within the class.  If you are using this pointer within the function only then you may not have problems; but if you try to use this pointer somewhere else within the class, the pointer is destroyed once the init function goes out of scope.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It is not null. I checked if the space pointer in the Enemy.h was not nullptr. It is not

Comment: @sji I checked it. It is not nullptr.

Comment: I forgot to tell: I initialize that space pointer to my import class named Space, in every class of my project. The program works fine with those space pointers if I don't call the inherited stuff of Enemy class.

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 Just because a pointer is not null doesn't mean it is valid.  And obviously you're doing something wrong, which no one will be able to tell you what it is until we get code that shows the full context.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What code do you want to have? I don't think people are going to like hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 You are mismanaging pointers.  What else can we say, given a few lines of code?

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 Giving disjoint bits and pieces of code won't really help.  There is a flow of execution that has to be seen, and we can't see it with what you're posting.  We have no idea where, when, or how `space` is initialized, whether it goes out of scope or invalidated in some way, whether the `Window` is a valid object when you use it, etc.

Comment: I have a question: When you inherit a class, does it also inherit all the pointers created in the base class?

Comment: I am sorry if this is too much code, I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Where is the actual `Space` object created and managed?  We still don't have a starting point (i.e. a `main` function).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The space.h gives an object pointing to itself to all other classes. I added the main function btw.

Comment: What does your memory debugger say?

Comment: If this is visual studio I would enable break on access violation in the Exceptions menu item of the Debug menu. Access violation will be in the win32 exceptions. After this is enabled debug the program and when Visual Studio breaks walk up the callstack to the line of your code that causes the access violation.

Comment: @drescherjm It was already enabled.

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 Pardon my ignorance, but your `main` function doesn't show any calls to the routines you posted except for `Space::init`.  When are these functions, other than `init`, called?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie First, the main just calls the init function. The space class will give a pointer to the object of itself to all the other classes. Main does nothing but "initializing" space class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You mean the for example getGame() functions? Those are called if one of my other classes need something from another class. It just gets the object to that class via Space. sorrry for bad English.

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 Just for kicks, add an empty destructor to `Space` object.  Put a breakpoint in that destructor.  Does it stop at that breakpoint before any of those other functions you posted get called?  If so, then that's your problem -- your `Space` object is going out of scope and all of your other objects wind up using an invalidated pointer.  Also, it would be a good time to lean about `std::shared_ptr`, as that is what your code should or could be using to alleviate such things from happening.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I made a destructor and set a breakpoint there, but the program still runs fine(without the calling of enemy class stuff of course)...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, I put a cout statement in the destructor but even when I exit my program, it is not called at all?

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 You are not probably setting the breakpoint correctly or you're running the wrong code.  On program exit, the destructor for all objects are called, so the breakpoint should have been fired.  If not, how else is that `Shape` object you have in main getting destroyed?  It is a local variable, so the destructor has to be called.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wrote constructor and destructor like this: Space::Space(){
 std::cout << "one";
}

Space::~Space(){
 std::cout << "two";
}


"one" gets printed, two does not.

Comment: To further elaborate I am not saying that the pointer to space is null, it is clearly 0x28. This however is not likely to be a bit of memory you are actually working in. This suggests to me that something is overwriting the memory referred to by the space variable. Try setting a data brake-point on &space and see if it gets hit anytime you don't expect.

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 Use a different criteria to determine when the destructor is called.  Using `cout` when the program is closing down is not a good idea.  Set a breakpoint, use `OutputDebugString` (if using Windows) or some other means.  Second, comment out your code to do the minimal, at least enough so that the exception is no longer thrown.  Then add code until the error appears.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  
I found out that the inherited playerObject contains null stuff, including the space object. Here a picture so it is clearer: prntscr.com/9btfim  However, the space object pointer in the Enemy class is valid(at least not null). – CPP_Newb69 23 mins ago

Comment: @CPP_Newb69 How many `space` member variables do you have?  That screen shot looks like you have multiple member variables named `space` for a single object hierarchy.  Look carefully again at your picture.  I think you mistakingly created a new member variable called `space`, believing it is the same `space` as the one declared in the base class.